# Auto login via moodle ( SAML )

Tags: python, django, moodle, saml, moodle-api

I'm using Django 1.6 for a backend and I've created a web application of meta player. I used OAuth2 for login.

Now I'd like to integrate my web Application in a moodle site, so here comes the question: How can I login to this web app via moodle account and then redirect to my web app site? For example I can now login to my web app via a facebook account cause there is an API for facebook, but I didn't find the relevant login API for moodle.
Besides this moodle uses SAML plugin for login, just like:

```
http://www.siteMoodle.com/auth/saml/login.php
```

Any idea? Thanks